# Scroll content that has position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a div (`.outer` - the viewport) with fixed height that contains another div (`.inner` - the content) which should be scrollable. The `.inner` div is positioned absolute with `bottom: 0` so that we can always see what's on the bottom of this div.

The problem is that when this `bottom: 0` is added to `.inner`, the scrollbar of the `.outer` becames gray and is not active. If we remove the `bottom: 0`, the scrollbar works, but we see the top, and not the bottom of the `.inner`.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        this content should be scolled to the bottom possibly with bottom: 0; AND we should still have to scrollbar the scroll to the top<br/>
        1<br/>
        2<br/>
        3<br/>
        4<br/>
        5<br/>
        6<br/>
        7<br/>
        8<br/>
        9<br/>
        10<br/>
        11<br/>
        12<br/>
        13<br/>
        14<br/>
        15<br/>
        16<br/>
        17<br/>
        18<br/>
        19<br/>
        20<br/>
        bottom (the scrollbar must be active)
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    height: 200px; 
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:270px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color:#aaa;
    width:250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAyhn/8/

Using jQuery to show the bottom of the .inner in the .outer's viewport is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer div isn't actually scrolled down in your example. What happens there is that the inner div is positioned in relation to the outer div. Since it's `bottom:0`, it means that it fills the entire div and the rest overflows above the element so there's nothing to scroll. (You can try setting it to `bottom:-10px` which gives 10 pixels room for a scroll.)

You can't set the scroll position with CSS alone, you need some JavaScript:

```
var outer = document.getElementsByClassName( 'outer' );
outer[0].scrollTo( 0, 10000 );​​​
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$( '.outer' ).scrollTop( 10000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually went a little further with you suggestion and I left `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to the `.inner` div (to have this content at the bottom (when the page is loaded) in case the `.inner` has less height that the `.outer`) and I added this:

```
if($('.outer').outerHeight() < $('.inner').outerHeight()) {
    $('.inner').css("bottom", "auto");
    $('.outer').scrollTop($('.inner').outerHeight());
}
```

This way I have the `.inner` shown at the bottom (if it has less height that the `.outer`) by default and I execute the code above everytime I put additional content to the `.inner` div to make an actual scroll if it is necessary.

Many thanks once again. :)